# Per client firewall settings

Tags: openvpn, firewalld

I've successfully set up an OpenVPN-Server and can connect to it from the internet. Now I'm trying to implement per-client firewall rules so different clients can only connect to certain addresses in my local network.

Sadly, I have no real idea how implement that. I've used CentOS and firewalld as the firewall on the server side.

I do know I could only push certain routes to clients, but so far, research on configuring a per-client firewall has yielded nothing.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We do it in the learn-address script:

```
learn-address         /opt/openvpn/scripts/openVPN-learnAddress.pl
```

The script is being called using the arguments "add", "update" or "delete" and the VPN-IP. When being called with add or update, an additional CN argument is passed.
We then use iptables to add/delete the rules for the user.